# Is ArcMap still 32-bit software?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 64bit

Is ArcMap 10.7.1 a 32- or 64-bit application?

I am familiar with 64-bit ArcGIS Pro, but not ArcMap.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, ArcMap, ArcCatalog, and the other UI tools of ArcGIS Desktop (except Pro) are still 32-bit at 10.7.x. They are also 32-bit at 10.8.x and 10.9.x.

Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of ArcPy exist for Python 2.7 (the latter in the optional 64-bit Background Geoprocessing in Desktop).  ArcGIS Server has been exclusively 64-bit since 10.1 (also Python 2.7).

64-bit ArcPy is available with ArcGIS Pro for Python 3.x, and the ArcGIS API for Python is also Python 3.x. There is also Python 3.x support available in ArcGIS Server 10.5.1+ (to support geoprocessing services published from Pro).